# Objects seem to merge and join, in Particle Property

Tags: particles, properties

Oranges in the image below seem to enter each other as they fall through(Particle property). How do I prevent it?

(Look at bottom of image for reference)

[image]

Comment: AFAIK particles can't self-collide in blender. With a small number of particles, like your oranges, such a feature would be perfectly feasible, but with increasing number of particles, the calculations would become incredibly complex. There used to be an addon called Molecular, that was supposedly able to do this, but I've never tried it, and I don't know if it's still being actively maintained. It may be possible in GeoNodes, using instances on points, but I haven't got that far in my learning GeoNodes yet.

Comment: Maybe instead of particles use rigid body?